# how to remove dynamically generated list item and replace with a new one

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

When a view loads I use axios to fetch some data from the server and show a count of a particular set of records. When the user performs an action, that count will change and I want to reach out to the server again and then show the updated count. Currently, the old value is still visible and then the new one is added underneath it which makes sense since that is what I have told the script to do. I would like to remove the existing element and replace it with the new data but since this data is dynamic, I can't access it like I would a normal class ie: `document.querySelector('.given')`

This is the function triggers when the page loads and I call it again once the user performs their action:

```
function getGivenCount() {

  axios.get('/account/givencount')
  .then(response => {
    document.querySelector('.counts').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', response.data.html);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    document.querySelector('.counts').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '0');
  });
 }
```

This is the controller code where the db query is done:

```
exports.getGivenCountSide = (req, res, next) => {
  Product.countDocuments({ userId: req.user, status: "given" })
    .then(given => {
      if (given > 0) {
      const givenTotal =
        '<li class="given"><a href="/account/given">Given <span class="nav-tag blue">' +
        given +
        "</span></a></li>";
      res.status(200).json({ html: givenTotal });
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({ html: '' });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
    });
};
```

This is the html that I append the `<li>` to

```
<ul class="counts">
</ul>
```

Comment: have you tried something like `document.querySelector('.counts').innerHTML = response.data;` ?

Comment: @dun32, where are you suggesting I put that code?

Comment: yes, sure ;-) just give a try to see if this solution suits your requirements

Comment: I guess you shouldn't write `response.data` but `response.html`